# waitFor criteria to check for existence of matching text in div's innerHTML?

Tags: groovy, webdriver, geb

After getting geb to click a login button, I want to wait for the next page to load.  The next page contains the following:

```
<th class="header">
   <div align="center">Welcome</div>
</th>
```

There isn't really any other content that allows me to test the page has loaded.

What should my `waitFor` expression look like?

```
$("input", value:"Login").click() // login action

// now wait for next page to load:
waitFor{ /* ?? */ }  // <-- how to locate the 'Welcome' text in /th/div/
```

Many thanks!

Comment: This worked:  `waitFor(10){ $("div", text:'Welcome') }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose it should be `waitFor{ $("div", text: "Welcome") }`

Comment: Yes,  I did actually have it working with this, but didn't realise it because the next line wasn't firing properly!!  Many thanks.